# Wicket - Load method in LoadableDetachableModel is not called after changing the value of the dropdown list

Tags: wicket

I am facing a problem with the update of a list that is filtered depending on the value of a dropdown.

This is a description of my model:

- I have a list of users
- When I click on a user, another list of orders of this user is
  displayed
- The list of orders is filtered according to the value of a dropdown
  containig a list of status

Please, see the image below:

[Users With orders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGvYZ.png)

The filter is working well, but the problem that I am facing is that once I choose an element from the dropdown, the list of orders is no longer updated when the user is changed.

This is a snippet of my code:

1. Construction of the Order Panel and instantiation of the list:

   ```
   public OrdersPanel(String id) 
   {
       super(id);
       this.setOutputMarkupId(true);
       setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag(true);

       IModel<List<Order>> orderListModel = new OrderListModel();
       orderListView = new orderListView("orderListView", orderListModel);
       //...
   }
   ```
2. OrderListModel:

   ```
   private final class OrderListModel extends LoadableDetachableModel<List<Order>> { 
       private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

       @Override
       protected List<Order> load() {
           //...

           //We set the variable allOrders in order to be used later in the filtering process

           //...
       }
   }
   ```
3. Construction of the dropdown:

   ```
   private class StatusDropDown extends CustomDropDown<String> implements IAjaxIndicatorAware {
       private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

       private StatusDropDown(String id) {
           super(id);
           this.setNullValid(true);
           StatusListModel statusModel = new StatusListModel();
           setChoices(statusModel);
           setChoiceRenderer(new StatusChoiceRenderer(statusModel));
       }

       @Override
       protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
           super.onUpdate(target);
           if (target != null) {
               new StatusDropDownRefreshEvent(this, target).fire();
               target.addComponent(this);
           }
       }

       /**
        * disable ajax marker for the form fields
        */
       public String getAjaxIndicatorMarkupId() {
           return null;
       }
   }
   ```
4. CustomDropDown (Must be used by the context of the project on which I am working):

   ```
   public class CustomDropDown<V> extends DropDownChoice<V> {

       private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
       public CustomDropDown(String id) {
           this(id, id);
       }

       public CustomDropDown(String id, String property) {
           super(id);
           setOutputMarkupId(true);

           setModel(new CustomComponentPropertyModel<V>(property));

           add(new AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior("onchange") {

               private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

               @Override
               protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                   new UpdateEvent(CustomDropDown.this, target).fire();
                   if (target != null) {
                       target.addComponent(CustomDropDown.this);
                   }

                   CustomDropDown.this.onUpdate(target);
               }
           });
       }

       @Override
       protected void onComponentTag(ComponentTag tag) {
           super.onComponentTag(tag);

           if (!isValid()) {
               tag.append("class", "invalid", " ");
               FeedbackMessage message = getFeedbackMessage();
               if (message != null) {
                   tag.put("title", message.getMessage().toString());
                   message.markRendered();
               }
           } else if (isRequired()) {
               tag.append("class", "red-background", " ");
           }

       }

       public void setWidth(String width) {
           this.add(new AttributeAppender("style", true, new Model<String>("width:" + width), ";"));
       }

       public CustomDropDown<V> setChoices(V... choices) {
           this.setChoices(Arrays.asList(choices));
           return this;
       }

       protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
       }
   }
   ```
5. StatusDropDownRefreshEvent listener:

   ```
   @AjaxUpdateEventListener
   public void statusDropDownRefreshPanel(StatusDropDownRefreshEvent event){
       if (event.getTarget() != null) {
           orderListView.setList(getOrdersByStatus(allOrders));
           event.getTarget().addComponent(this);
       }
   }
   ```
6. Changing of the user:
   When the user is changed, an update event is fired from the users panel, and then cached in the orders panel:

   ```
   @AjaxUpdateEventListener
   public void refreshPanel(CustomerOrderRefreshEvent event) {

       if (event.getTarget() != null) {
           event.getTarget().addComponent(this);
           this.onBeforeRender();
       }
   }
   ```
7. onBeforeRender() to determin the visibility of the panel (if no order is available then the orders panel is not visible)

   ```
   @Override
   public void onBeforeRender() {
       setVisibilityAllowed(checkVisibility());
       super.onBeforeRender();
   }
   ```
8. Finally, the checkVisibility Method:

   ```
   private boolean checkVisibility() {
       if (isUserChanged()) {
           List<Order> src = orderListView.getModelObject();
           statusDropDown.setDefaultModelObject(null);
           return CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(src);
       }

       return true;
   }
   ```

My main problem is that the changing of the selected user doesn't update the list of orders once a status is chosen from the list.

Thank you very much for your replies and your time.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem.

The list of orders wasn't updated because The method getObject was called on the wrong object.

The call of the load() method can be done via getObject(), but the condition is: The object must be detached (See the implementation of getObject() at [this link](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Detachable+Models))

The detached object in my case is the orderListModel and not the orderListView, so this is what I added to my code:

```
//Set the content of the list model
List<Order> orders = orderListModel.getObject(); //This invokes the load method
//Update the content of the list
orderListView.setList(orders);
```